# Django PUT method not returning HttpResponse object

Tags: django, python-2.7, cross-domain

I am implementing GET,POST,PUT methods using django 's generic views (django.views.generic.base).

GET and POST methods are working fine.
However, the PUT method is not returning any HttpResponse object, although I am getting a code 200 OK from server but no data.

I think this may be the issue related to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

Can anyone point me to the right direction to solve this issue ?

I am using nginx + uwsgi for deplyoment.

---

Edit:
I have enabled the nginx server to handle PUT and OPTIONS http verbs.

---

Here is my PUT code :

```
def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Update from the controller with info that all the commands has
    been successfully executed on that controller
    :param mac:
    :param request:
    :param args:
    :param kwargs:
    """
self.true_response["mac"] = None
self.false_response["mac"] = None
if request.method == 'PUT': 
        if "mac" in kwargs:
                mac = kwargs["mac"]
        self.true_response["mac"] = mac
        self.false_response["mac"] = mac
        query = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM controller WHERE \
            `controller_mac` = '%s'" % mac
            cursor = connections['cnms'].cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            if not result[0][0]:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(self.false_response))
        try:
            query = """ UPDATE command SET command_status = 2 WHERE \
                command_mac '%s'""" % mac
            cursor = connections['cnms'].cursor()
            cursor.execute(query)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(self.true_response))
        except Exception as error:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(self.false_response))
        else:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status" : "false"}))
else:
    return HttpResponse("Method is Not Supported")
```

Comment: can you post the code of your View?

Comment: @lai :: I have posted my PUT code in question

Answer (score 0):

So, firstly, your DB query is not secure, depending on what "mac" is supposed to contain.
Check out [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python) for more details on how to address this.

Secondly do you know where your code branches ?

Does the "mac" kwarg get passed properly to the method?

As far as I am concerned, I also use to specify explicitly the mimetype in json responses, e.g.:

```
HttpResponse(json_dictionary, mimetype="application/json; charset=utf-8")
```

Perhaps that may help?